# Xubuntu 11.04 and CANON PowerShot A470

Tags: usb, xubuntu, camera, canon

I have a digital camera CANON PowerShot A470, and Xubuntu 11.04 installed on my PC. When i attach the camera to PC Xubuntu don't mount it, and don't show attached device...

How i can use camera on Xubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I’ve had the same problem and I solved it by installing Nautilus. Unlike Thunar (the default file browser for Xubuntu), Nautilus will show the camera in the sidebar.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but I thought I would post what worked for me. I own a Canon Powershot SX150 IS and am running xubuntu 10.04. The file browser, Gigolo, works great for getting the files off the camera onto the computer.

Comment: I have had a similar problem with PowerShot S90. It does not connect automatically but connecting it through Gigolo and then using Thunar works ok.

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with some PowerShot models.
The only thing that worked for me, was taking the SDcard out of the camera, and copy the files from that. 
I think it has something to do with some Canon models don't mount their memory like usual "external drives".